# Help referencing widgets in cloned copies of wxDesigner panel

Tags: wxpython

I'm fairly new to wx.python programming, and am having trouble accomplishing my goal. I'm designing a program that inspects directories for particular file characteristics, and returns information about the directories and files to the user.  The user will then make choices for each directory. These choices get passed back to the controlling program.
Because the format of information presented to the user for each of x directories is the same, I created panels in wxDesigner to display and interact with this information  These panels are inserted x number of times into a scrolled panel.  (I believe that wxDesigner actually returns a parent sizer that is inserted into my main sizer in the scroll panel.)  So far so good...

My troube starts when I try to access the different forms that appear. Because I'm inserting a form created in wxDesigner, the ID's are assigned one time and apply to all copies of the form.  Since I'm inserting copies of an entire form, I can't create separate ID for each of the duplicated fields as I've seen done in the many examples (during my many hours of searching the net) of multiple widgets created and inserted into a panel at runtime.

I'm adding the forms in an iterate loop. I've tried to give the instances of the inserted form separate names, I've reassigned the ID using SetId(), NewId() etc without luck. I've also tried using SetName() as well, but in both approaches, I keep ending up with ID's or Names assigned on the last inserted form referencing all the matching widgets on all the forms.

I've hit numerous dead-ends, and was next thinking of creating separate panels as I inserted the wxDesigner objects. But that would only work if I am able to reference a widget by parent.widget, and I haven't seen any examples of doing this. I also thought about writing a proceedure in the wxDesigner xxx_wdr.py file (once I know it won't change) that generates separate ID's for each inserted instance.  But before I bang my head agains the wall any more, I thought I'd ask for help to know which direction to travel...

I could show my code (one version of the many attempts) if it's a matter of a small detail, but let's start wth suggestions of the general approach one would take in this situation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions, definitely useful information! I can't go the class panel approach since I can't edit the wxPython generated code, but it was useful to see how it's done.

My solution was to reassign static Id's in my code via SetId() to a number composed of a fixed ID for the particular widget, plus t the number of the iteration that inserted the form. This created a unique id for each widget/form.  I used a a dictionary (thanks, Mike), to find the base part of the id, and could append the iteration count to reference them at any time. I used a procedure to simplify finding the widget id so I didn't need to type the 'FindWindow....' bit repeatedly. There are probably more elegant ways, but this works:

```
        widgetId = {
        'btn' : 6000,
        'textctrl' : 6010,
        'textlbl' :6020 }

    def getWidget(self, widget, formNo ):
        '''Finds widget window via lookup of re-assigned widget ID #'s'''
        widget = self.FindWindowById(self.widgetId[widget] + formNo)
        return widget

    def cloneWX(self):
        '''Reassign ID at time of cloning'''
        for  formNo in range(self.clones):
            # Insert the cloned form (a BoxSizer created by wxDesigner) into this copy:
            self.form = NewDialog( self.panel1, True, set_sizer = False)
            self.grid.Add(self.form, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=10)

            # Set initial references:
            self.textlbl = self.FindWindowById( ID_TEXT )
            self.textctrl = self.FindWindowById( ID_TEXTCTRL)
            self.btn = self.FindWindowById( ID_BUTTON_1 )

            # Reset ID based on form number: (Can reference via dictionary instead))
            self.btn.SetId(6000 + formNo)
            self.textctrl.SetId(6010 + formNo)
            self.textlbl.SetId(6020 + formNo)

            # Bind events to new ID references:
            wx.EVT_BUTTON(self, 6000 + formNo, self.OnBtn)

    def OnBtn(self, event):
        event_object = event.GetEventObject()
        # From the event id, extract the form number where this widget appears :
        formNo = event_object.GetId() - self.widgetId['btn']

        textctrl = self.getWidget('textctrl', formNo)
        textlbl = self.getWidget('textlbl', formNo)
        textlbl.SetLabel(textctrl.GetValue())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with wxDesigner, but if you have multiple, identical copies of the same wx.Panel (or anything), it's a good idea to add them to a `list` or `dict` as you add them to your main form.  This will let you access them all individually, as well as any of their children (through parent.widget as you mentioned).  You could also wrap the panels in your own class with accessor functions to retrieve values from outside the class without calling the widgets directly.

Pseudocode:

```
class CustomPanel:
    def __init__(self, parent, etc):
        GeneratedPanel.__init__(self, parent, etc)

    def GetFirstThing(self):
        return self.FirstThing.GetValue()

    def GetSecondThing(self):
        return self.SecondThing.GetValue()

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, parent, etc)
        #...
        self.panels = []
        for i in range(10):
            self.panels.append(CustomPanel(self, etc))

    def GetSomeValue(self, index):
        return self.panels[index].GetFirstThing()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace the id line of code with wx.ID_ANY. Also, you can set a widget's name when you instantiate it. Here's an example:

btn = wx.Button(parent, name="myBtn")

If you need to get a child widget from its parent, then you'll have to do something like this:

```
children = parent.GetChildren()

for child in children:
   if child.GetName() == "someName":  # or child.GetId() or whatever
      # do something here
```

I don't know if that will help you or not.